# Phonegap CLI with Windows Phone 7 - Can't find the cordovastarter to build wp7

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-7.1.1, cordova-3

I have installed Phonegap3.0 via CLI. I am trying to run a sample project for android and wp7 in windows 7 machine.

My installation path for project is

```
 E:\workspace\HelloWorld
```

inside i found

```
"merges,platform,plugins,www,.codova" folders.
```

After that i run the below command

```
"phonegap local build android" in  cmd
```

Then inside platform folder i found android folder with project sturcture. So now i can run this folder by importing in eclipse...

After that for windows i run the below command

```
 "phonegap local build wp7"
```

I found the wp7 folder inside E:\workspace\HelloWorld\platform\wp7. Now i want to know how to create a cordovastarter for the project to run in local visual studio 2010 express.

Suggest me how to run wp7 project with phonegap3.0 in visual studio  express

Answer (score 2):

You need the Windows Phone SDK 7.1 which you can download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570).
The requirements for the SDK are:

- Windows® Vista® (x86 and x64) with Service Pack 2 all editions except Starter Edition
- Windows 7 (x86 and x64) with all editions except Starter Edition
- 4 GB of free disk space
- 3 GB RAM
- Windows Phone Emulator requires a DirectX 10 or above capable graphics card with a WDDM 1.1 driver

In the SDK included is a Visual Studio Express. But if you already have a Visual Studio 2010 SP1 installed, the SDK will be hooked there.

Now if you run the following command in your project:

```
phonegap local build wp7
```

the`/platforms/wp7` folder should contain a whole Visual Studio project that looks like this.

[image: Project in wp7 folder]

You may now simply open the `*.sln` File and it should open up your project. There you may directly start the project with the Windows Phone Emulator if the SDK has been installed correctly.

[image: HelloWorld project with installed SDK in VS 2010]

If you still have issues, maybe [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_wp8_index.md.html#Windows%20Phone%20Platform%20Guide) Guide may solve them.